# C# Why do String.IndexOf(string) and ReadOnlySpan.IndexOf(string) return different values

Tags: c#

In the below code, the string.IndexOf() returns a positive integer indicating success.  The span version returns -1, indicating failure.  Why is this.

```
string str = "Something Something Something myvalue";

ReadOnlySpan<string> span = new(str);

var indexWithString = str.IndexOf(@"myvalue");

var indexWithSpan = span.IndexOf(@"myvalue");
```

The same holds for Contains().

Comment: Maybe because one of them is `a.IndexOf` and the other is `s.IndexOf`. You didn't specify `a` or `s` - they are probably different.

Comment: A `string` can be represented by a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, not by a `ReadOnlySpan<string>`

Comment: I think you meant `ReadOnlySpan<char> span = str.AsSpan();`  ? (which is a zero-copy operation that creates a span over an existing string, without allocating anything)

Comment: Whoops, sorry in trying making my question concise I changed only some variable names but not all.  Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line:

```
ReadOnlySpan<string> span = new(str);
```

calls the [ReadOnlySpan(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-readonlyspan-1-ctor(-0@)) ctor:

> Creates a new ReadOnlySpan of length 1 around the specified reference.

And the [ReadOnlySpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?view=net-7.0) is:

> Provides a type-safe and memory-safe read-only representation of a contiguous region of arbitrary memory.
> A `ReadOnlySpan<T>` instance is often used to reference the elements of an array or a portion of an array.

I.e. `ReadOnlySpan<string>` represents a collection of strings.

So those two a completely different operations, first one is basically searching for `"myvalue"` in a collection of strings (which has only one string - `str`, i.e. is equivalent of `new List<string>{ str }.IndexOf("myvalue")`) while the second one searches for substring in the string.

I.e. for the first one the following:

```
string str = "Something Something Something myvalue";
ReadOnlySpan<string> span = new(str);
Console.WriteLine(span.Contains(str));
```

Will print `True`

Answer (score 5):

Non-compiling example code aside, it appears to fail because `ReadOnlySpan<string>` is not a string. It's a collection of strings. You're not searching for the index of the text within the string you put in the span, but rather the index of the whole string. Try the below code to see this behavior:

```
string str = "Something Something Something myvalue";

ReadOnlySpan<string> span = new(str);

var indexWithString = str.IndexOf(@"myvalue");
Console.WriteLine(indexWithString); // Outputs 30

var indexWithSpan = span.IndexOf(@"myvalue");
Console.WriteLine(indexWithSpan); // Outputs -1

var indexCheat = span.IndexOf(str);
Console.WriteLine(indexCheat); // Outputs 0, because it matches the string in first place of this span.
```